# Getting Facebook URL shares count returns HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden on frequently visited site

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On one of my PHP sites I use following code to get Facebook share count of each website subpages:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
if(isset($json['share']['share_count'])){
    return intval( $json['share']['share_count'] );
} else { 
  return 0;
}
```

The code works fine on a not so much attended website.
But when I used that code on a frequently visited site, it gives me zero shares count and following warning:

Warning: Warning (2): file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/?id=...): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

I'm guessing that maybe I call to many requests to the http://graph.facebook.com/?id= URL. My question is how do I solve this problem? I need to update the shares count not less than in 10-15 minutes interval for each subpage. And there are more than 2000 of them. And the users visiting whole website is a huge number.

Comment: According to [their documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting) you should be able to check your [Apps Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) to see if you are being rate-limited by the API.

Comment: I've registered at developers.facebook.com and got an APP ID, but I just use above code. Should I use something more?

Answer (score 0):

You really should not call the api for every single page hit, that would definitely hit rate limits. There are 2 things you should do:

- Create an App and use an **App Access Token** for every API call: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- Cache the API result and only update it once in a while with a cron job - or **on page hit if the last result is older than a specific time range**. That would be a better solution if you need to keep the share count up to date. A cron job for 2000 API calls would definitely hit API limits too. Make sure you don´t use all those API calls in a short time, implement some timeout between a batch of API calls.

If that does not work, you need to reduce the amount of API calls.

Comment: Yes, I cached the results in DB and used 10 minutes time range. But it still generated too many calls. Anyway I followed your suggestion - I've created an app, got an app ID and app secret and with it I got my access token ( app_ID|app_secret ) . Now I query the graph.facebook.com/?id={url}&access_token={access_token}&fie‌​lds=engagement but I get the error in return: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request. It is strange, because when I fire the same URL in browser, it works and displays needed data. Do you have any idea why I get such error?

Comment: Solved the issue... Should have used &amp; instead of & in URL for file_get_contents()

Comment: Can you share the full code? I am getting the same error. Too many calls? What did you us the &amp;  ??? I don't understand how you used that. Thanks